# text-overflow:ellipsis with MathJax?

Tags: mathjax, css

Is it possible to get `text-overflow:ellipsis` to work with MathJax?

Here is a (non-working) example ([on `JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/4qSr4/))

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<div id="test">
\[
\text{2014-01-05} \quad
\begin{cases} \text{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum} \\
\text{Lorem ipsum} \\
\text{Lorem ipsum} \\
\end{cases}
\]
</div>

<div id="test">
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#test{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As you can see, `text-overflow:ellipsis` works for the `div` without any MathJax content but not for the `div` with MathJax content. Is there any solution or workaround?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way of making this work.

While [the MathML spec](http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.html#chapter2_interf.toplevel.atts) provides two comparable values for `overflow` -- `truncate` and `elide` -- neither one is implemented in MathJax yet.

On the bright side, [linebreaking is supported](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-line-breaking) for display-style mathematics.

---

Addendum: some restrictions apply. Not all linebreaking methods are supported; in particular,  linebreaking within token elements and some alignment options are not supported.